# placement of java classes when executing from cmd

Tags: java

I have two java classes A and B, both within the mypack package

```
package mypack
class A {
   public static void main (String args[]) {
    B b = new B();
     ...  
        }
   }

package mypack
class B {....}
```

when compiling from the console I do this

```
javac -cp somepath .\mypack\*.java
```

this will generate the class files for me inside the mypack folder. Now if I try to run the .class files that are inside the mypack folder with this command

```
java -cp somepath mypack.A
```

I will get this error this error

*Error: could not find or load main class mypack.A*

but if I move the class files from mypack folder to its parent folder and execute this line again

```
java -cp somepath mypack.A
```

it will execute correctly.

Could someone explain to me why this is happening?

with regards,

es

Comment: I think you will need to clarify what your classpath parameter is exactly and what the current directory in which you are running the java command is.

Comment: I am finding this hard to believe. I would have expected exactly the reverse behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-cp allows you to specify location of class files. In order to use -cp somepath you have to have following structure

```
somepath
|
+-mypack
  |
  +- A.class
  +- B.class
```

after compilation, you can put class files (with directory structure reflecting packages) anywhere you like.

Update:

yes, this is correct. You are not obliged to put compiled classes into "somepath". You can use any location you like. In fact, you can do something like this:

```
> javac -d target .\mypack\*.java # this will put 
                                  # compiled classes inside "target"
```

Then, you can run your code that way:

```
> java -cp target mypack.A
```

Instead of "target" you can put any location you like.

Comment: while you don't have to put the mypack inside the somepath folder, but since this directed me to the correct answer I marked it. I only needed to add the correct path within the -cp, as so:  -cp "somepath";"path to the mypack parent folder"